# MultiStore 1.4.2 - mage.php not found

Tags: magento-1.4

I have my main store installed in the httpdocs under the main domain and it is working just fine.  Now I created a subdomain partners.mydomain.com, with the folder located in httpdocs (httpdocs > partners).  I set up the second store in the manage stores and change the URL in the configuration for that store.  And copied the .htaccess file and index.php file into that folder.

I’ve added this to my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)http://partners.mydomain.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:partners_en]
```

And change to index.php to

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

and

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = 'partners_en';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = 'store';    

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

I had no problem with this on 1.6, but getting an error saying “../app/mage.php was not found” on 1.4.2.

Any one have a solution?

Comment: If you ever see this error : https://snag.gy/YLwvBm.jpg after created store i am getting above error, backend screenshot:  https://snag.gy/I1mLRz.jpg how can i solve this error..

Answer (score 1):

```
$compilerConfig = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/includes/config.php';

$mageFilename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/magento/app/Mage.php';
```

Use this. It worked for me.

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a server variable that represents the base directory that your code is located within.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `/` before `..` like this:

```
$mageFilename = '/../app/Mage.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../includes/config.php';

$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
```